# Какой алгоритм будет уместен для передачи массива?

Tags: c++, tcpclient

Делаю передачу аудио данных от клиента к серверу по TCP.
Описывать сервер не буду, на его стороне все хорошо работает.

На клиенте я открываю аудио файл, читаю его в бинарном виде, записываю весь результат выборки в массив и закрываю файл. Длину массива также подсчитываю. Не могу только понять, как правильно за каждую итерацию отправлять порцию в 320 байт массива в TCP до его окончания? подскажите пожалуйста. Вот что в данный момент у меня получилось, комментариями пометил.

```
if (OpenDialog1->FileName  != "") { // Если файл выбран
int step_size = 320;

AnsiString get_file = OpenDialog1->FileName;
ifstream audio;
audio.open(get_file.c_str(), ios::binary);

if (audio.is_open()) { // Если файл открыт
    audio.seekg(0, audio.end);  // Конец файла
    int len = audio.tellg();  // Определяем размер файла
    ProgressBar1->Position = 0;
    ProgressBar1->Max = len;  // Корректируем прогресс бар
    audio.seekg(0, audio.beg);  // В начало файла

    char *pData = new char[len];
    audio.read(pData, len); // Читаем и записываем pData
    audio.close(); // Закрываем файл

    while (true) {  // true пока для теста

        /* Здесь необходимо отправить pData в таком виде но по 320 байт
        Form1->IdTCPClient1->Socket->WriteLn(pData);
        */

        ProgressBar1->Position += step_size;

        Sleep(40); // Тормозим итерацию на 40мс
    }

} else {  // Если файл не открыт
    Memo1->Lines->Add("Ошибка открытия файла: " + OpenDialog1->FileName);
}

} else {  // Если файл не выбран
    Memo1->Lines->Add("Файл для трансляции не выбран!");
}
```

Соединение TCP было заранее установлено и активно на момент передачи данных.

Comment: Откуда требование в 320 байт, это ведь очень мало и приведет к срабатыванию алгоритма Нейгла и прочим пакостям?

Comment: TCP является поточным протоколом, соответственно передаваемые данные не разделяются на порции. Количество вызовов функции записи в сокет никакой роли не играет.

Comment: @user7860670 - кроме создания тормозов и срабатывания защиты от насыщения сети мелкими пакетами.

Comment: Частота дискретизации wav файла в моем случае 8000 сэмплов в секунду (необходимость). Для кодирования 1 сэмпла аудио в формате G.711U требуется 1 байт. Это значит, что данные в формате G.711U нужно отправлять со скоростью 8000 байт в секунду. Эти 8000 байт нужно разделить на порции. Например, 25 порций по 320 байт или 8 порций по 1000 байт и отправлять их с равными интервалами времени.

Comment: @Сергей вы напрасно пытаетесь переизобрести RTP. Особенно, если потери фреймов допустимы.

Comment: @gbg я это не пытаюсь сделать. Мне нужно просто отправить серверу массив данных и даже не ждать от него ответа. Открыть сокет - отправить - закрыть сокет :)

Comment: Так, у вас массив уже готов, или вы хотите посылать данные по мере получения?

Comment: @gbg Данные уже все получены и записаны в массив. Как отправить его сразу весь я понимаю, но я бы хотел это сделать порциями как писал выше.

Comment: У вас не получится это сделать порциями желаемого размера, вам TCP не даст. Он будет склеивать ваши данные в пакеты как ему вздумается.

Comment: Если потери пакетов допустимы, есть протокол RTP/UDP, который решает вашу задачу.

Comment: @Сергей "работает" не означает "работает правильно". Особенно плохо ваша идея будет работать через Интернет, где задержки случайные.

Comment: @gbg делал на python таким способом, прекрасно работало) 
цикл
data = array[i:i + buffer_size]
i += buffer_size
s.send(data)

Comment: Ну и как вы проверили, что у вас на выходе получаются пакеты по 320 байт? TCP просто склеивал ваши данные, как ему удобно.

Comment: @gbg отправлял разделитель между посылками.

Comment: @Сергей, а на приемном конце вы этот звук воспроизводили и ничего не заикалось?

Comment: @gbg воспроизводил и звук был отличным. Пытаюсь реализовать питоновский код на c++ и все никак.. (

Comment: Если ваше приложение будет работать через интернет, оно с большой долей вероятности будет работать плохо, вас это устроит?

Comment: @gbg к счастью она не планировалась для работы через интернет.)) Только в лс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наиболее оптимальный (и транслируемый в учебниках) метод - пытаться записать в сокет сразу весь массив.

-это приведет к сокращению числа системных вызовов

-это даст возможность TCP сделать свою работу (потому что он Trasmision Control Protocol) наиболее оптимальным образом

Сам алгоритм такой:

```
char* base   = //указатель на начало данных
size_t total = 320;
size_t size  = 0;
while(size<total)
{
     const int res = send(sock, base + size, total - size, ...);
     if(res <=0)
     {
         //обработать ошибку
     }
     size+=res;
}
```

То что вы хотите сделать - неоптимально, ненадежно, нестабильно и неправильно.

Тем не менее, можно сделать поведение, похожее на Питон - вам нужно каждую порцию ваших данных в 320 байт отправлять вышеописанным алгоритмом.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Попробую сделать как вы написали.

Comment: ваш вариант отлично отработал. Благодарю.